# Referencing issue in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, citations

Every time I re-open my document on Word 2013, my references are not recognized, or to put it differently, my current list of references are cleared.

I'm using the IEEE style of referencing and the numbers convert to static text every time I open my document.

My project is due soon and I can't afford to re enter the citations, even though the sources remain in my master list.

I would be unbelievably grateful if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.